# ASP.NET FileUpload control's Change Event

Tags: asp.net

I am having trouble using FileUpload control, I want to validate image length, size, format etc. and wanted to display it on ImageControl when successfully validated. This I did through another button click's event but I wanted this to be done on client side's 'OK/OPEN' and 'CANCEL' buttons when 'Browse File' window opens. Pls help.

Comment: what you have do so far ?
show your code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why peoples are voting negatively this question. It might be a stupid question or I was not explained enough. I m sorry for that. Any way I found the solution.

I was exploring an event when User selects an Image file of FileUpload from 'Browse File' dialog box.

My code is as follows:

`<asp:FileUpload ID="imgUpload" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" Width="200px"      Height="24px" ToolTip="Browse patient image " />`

`<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" runat="server" OnClick="imgBtn_Click" ImageUrl="~/IMAGES/Upload-icon.png" Height="24px" ToolTip="Upload patient image" />`

Upload means validate the image and put it in a Session variable and display it on Image control. Later when I click save button it Byte[] array gets save into the database.

`

```
protected void imgBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Byte[] imgByte = null;
        const int PROD_IMG_MAX_WIDTH = 130;
        const int PROD_IMG_HEIGHT = 130;
        imgEmp.Visible = false;
        if (imgUpload.HasFile && imgUpload.PostedFile != null && IsFileValid())
        {
            HttpPostedFile File1 = imgUpload.PostedFile;
            imgByte = new Byte[File1.ContentLength];
            File1.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File1.ContentLength);
            Session["binaryImage"] = imgByte;
            System.Drawing.Image UploadedImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);
            object o = UploadedImage.Size;
            if (UploadedImage.Width > PROD_IMG_MAX_WIDTH && UploadedImage.Height > PROD_IMG_HEIGHT && File1.ContentLength > 1048576)
            {
                DisplayMessage("Size of image is not correct!");
                Session["binaryImage"] = null;
                imgEmp.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                imgEmp.Font.Size = FontUnit.Medium;
            }
            else
            {
                imgEmp.Height = 100;
                imgEmp.Width = 90;
                imgEmp.Visible = true;
                imgEmp.ImageUrl = "~/ADMIN/MASTERS/ImgDisp.aspx";
                ViewState["imgUploadedPhotoName"] = imgUpload.FileName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayMessage("Browse valid image!");
            imgEmp.Visible = true;
        }
    }`
```

Finally i added this script

`$(document).ready(function () {
            var labelID = $('#<%= imgUpload.ClientID %>');

            var uploadBtnId = $('#<%= imgBtn.ClientID %>');
            uploadBtnId.css('display','none');
            labelID.bind('change', function () {

                uploadBtnId.trigger('click');
            });
        })`